# c++11, c++14, c++17? What to use?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I used to program in C++ professionally, but that was ages ago. Now I'm returning to it.  Boy, has C++ evolved!

I've been studying up on the latest features introduced in C++11, including lambda expressions, good multi-threading support (stuff that previously only boost supported), etc.

Lately, on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine, I've been compiling like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 filename.cpp
```

However, apparently there's also C++14 and C++17. If I want to be fully up-to-date with modern C++ programming practices, should I be compiling like this instead?

```
g++ -std=c++17 filename.cpp
```

Assuming my code compiles either way, is there any reason why I shouldn't just compile all of my new code using C++17?

I'm already delving into stuff like `shared_timed_mutex`, which is in C++14, but haven't yet played with even newer stuff, like `atomic`, which is in C++17. So, in some respects, I suppose I'll need C++17 eventually.

I'm just trying to understand if there's any harm in me just using C++17 always when compiling.

To provide more context, I'm only compiling for one platform (Ubuntu Linux).  There's no need to think about backward compatibility, or other operating systems.  When you take that into account, with my desire to learn the latest C++ features, is there any reason why I shouldn't just always compile with C++17?

Or, restated another way, as of today's date, April 11 2018, can I assume that compiling with `-std=c++17` uses fully released features, nothing of which is experimental?

Comment: The only real downside is that (unless you do the appropriate trickery) you end up depending on the newer standard library. That's maybe a problem if you want to publish your software somewhere that isn't available.

Comment: Well, it's 2018, C++17 was published last year, so none of the features enabled by `-std=c++17` are experimental.

Comment: Go with the latest standard you have available. No reason not to, unless you need to support old compilers.

Comment: I'd use the C++17 flag by default, it's the default in the latest version of clang too iirc. You should use the latest language features as long as you don't need to support builds on older compilers or embedded platforms that only have outdated compilers, as mentioned above.

Comment: I've voted to close as opinion-based.   There are a lot of things that go into a decision of which language/standard to go with, including QUALITY of available compilers and libraries for each, availability of such compilers and libraries that target your choice of hardware, the amount of legacy code that uses features from older standards that are not supported in newer standards, requirements to support older versus newer compilers, etc etc .....

Comment: FYI Ubuntu 16.04 only ships with GCC 5.4 which only has experimental support for some C++17 features. I wouldn't advise compiling with `-std=c++17` with this version. You'll need GCC 7.x for full C++17 support. Easiest way to get that is to either wait till 18.04 is released at the end of this month or use an [unofficial repository](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-7.2).

Comment: Fibbles, thanks for your answer.  If people hadn't objected to my question as opinion-based and you had answered this question, I'd mark your comment as the preferred answer.

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on many factors, but the main question is what is target of your library or application?
What platforms are you planing to support?

There are some platforms which do not have the newest version of C++ compiler. In fact there are some platform which can you provide only C++03.

Since new version of C++ introduce some new cool features and standard library API, it the best to use the newest C++ which will cover all platforms which you are planing to use.

If you do not know what platform to use, think about features of C++ you whish to use and use minimal version of C++ which can provide them. This way you can postpone decision of supported platforms for a later time.